# Convert Current Timestamp UTC to CET

Tags: presto, amazon-athena, trino

I'm trying to find a way to convert the current_timestamp into a different time zone.

The function **current_timestamp** in Simba Athena gives me the timestamp in UTC by default.
I would like to get this same timestamp in the CET timezone. Please note that I would like to automate this conversion in my query.

I tried the *convert_timezone('CET', current_timestamp)* function, but it's not recognized in AWS Athena

In simpler works, I'm looking for a substitute for the SQL Server function GETUTCDATE() in Presto, except that i would like to get the CET timestamp. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`current_timestamp`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?highlight=current_timestamp#current_timestamp) in Trino (formerly known as Presto SQL) returns a `timestamp with time zone` value in terms of the current session time zone. For instance, if the client is in `America/Los_Angeles` time zone:

```
trino> select current_timestamp;
                    _col0
---------------------------------------------
 2020-08-26 09:14:43.259 America/Los_Angeles
(1 row)
```

You can check what's the current timezone for the session with [`current_timezone()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?highlight=current_timestamp#current_timezone):

```
trino> select current_timezone();
        _col0
---------------------
 America/Los_Angeles
(1 row)
```

To convert a `timestamp with time zone` to another time zone, you can use the [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?highlight=current_timestamp#time-zone-conversion) syntax:

```
trino> select current_timestamp at time zone 'America/New_York';
                  _col0
------------------------------------------
 2020-08-26 12:18:37.901 America/New_York
(1 row)
```